# How to prove this series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_j a_{j+1}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If $a_j>0$ for every $j$ and if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ converges then prove that
$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_j a_{j+1}}$ converges. I want to use arithmetic mean${}>{}$geometric mean, but I don't know how to show the series $\sum \frac{a_j +a_{j+1}}{2}$ converges.

Comment: Hint: $$
\sum_{j\geq 1} {\frac{{a_j  + a_{j + 1} }}{2}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\geq 1} {a_j }  + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\geq 1} {a_{j + 1} } < \sum_{j\geq 1} a_j
$$

Comment: why the last step in your equality?

Comment: @Gary Don't you need to show absolute convergence before you can rearrange the summation?

Comment: @Kaind The terms are positive (by assumption), so the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Gary No, as the terms are positive, absolute convergence is equivalent to convergence. But how do you show the series is convergent, (you can't rearrange it, as you haven't shown it converges yet).

Comment: @Kaind The $\sum\nolimits_{j \ge 1} {a_{j} }$ and $\sum\nolimits_{j \ge 1} {a_{j + 1} }$ are (absolutely) convergent by assumtion. Thus, $$
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j \ge 1} {a_j }  + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j \ge 1} {a_{j + 1} }  = \sum\limits_{j \ge 1} {\frac{{a_j  + a_{j + 1} }}{2}} .
$$

Comment: Yes, we need to start from the other way around. StubbornAtom's link does the same.

Comment: @Kaind The relation "=" is a symmetric relation.

Comment: @Gary Yes, I know. My point was that you are rearranging the series $\sum_n a_n$ and not the series $\sum_n \frac{a_n + a_{n+1}}{2}$.

Comment: @Kaind Yes, but who said otherwise? You can read my line from right to left if you like. I do not see why you are making a huge deal about this.

Answer (score 2):

$0<\sqrt{a_ja_{j+1}}\le \max (a_j,a_{j+1})<\max (a_j,a_{j+1})+\min (a_j,a_{j+1})=a_j+a_{j+1}.$

Let $A(j)=\sum_{n=1}^ja_n.$ Let $b_n=a_n+a_{n+1}.$ Let $B(j)=\sum_{n=1}^jb_j.$

Suppose $A(j)\to L$ as $j\to\infty.$

Given any $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $j_{\epsilon} \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall j>j_{\epsilon}\,(\,|-L+A(j)|<\epsilon /2 ),$ and hence also $\forall j>j_{\epsilon}\,(\,|-L+A(j+1)|<\epsilon /2).$

Observe that $B(j)=A(j)+A(j+1)-a_1$ and therefore for all $j>j_{\epsilon}$ we have $$|-(2L-a_1)+B(j)|=|(-L+A(j))+(-L+A(j+1)|\le$$ $$\le |L+A(j)|+|-L+A(j+1)| <\epsilon /2+\epsilon /2=\epsilon.$$

So $B(j)$ converges to $2L-a_1$ as $j\to\infty.$

In the 1700's you could say: When $j$ and $j+1$ are infinitely large then $A(j)$ and $A(j+1)$ are infinitely close to $L$ so $B(j)=A(j)+A(j+1)-a_1$ is infinitely close to $L+L-a_1.$

Comment: But why $a_j+a_{j+1}$ converges?

Comment: @Mariana . I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{a_j +a_{j+1}}{2} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \left( \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j \right) + \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{j+1} \right) \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \Big( \big( a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + \cdots\big) \tag 1 \\
& \qquad\qquad{}+\big(a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + \cdots \big) \Big) \tag 2
\end{align}

The series on line $(1)$ converges if and only if that on line $(2)$ converges since just adding or taking away a single term (although it changes the value of the sum) does not change convergence or divergence.

Comment: so converge + converge = converge?

Comment: @Mariana : That works except in cases of conditional converges, i.e. except in cases where the sum of the positive terms and the sum of the negative terms both diverge to infinity.

Comment: I still think this is not very rigorous. Can we show it in terms of partial sum? Since I didn't see  converge + converge = converge in the book.

Comment: @Mariana : $$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j + \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \\ {} \\
= {} & \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^N a_j + \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^N b_k \tag 1 \\ {} \\
= {} & \lim_{N\to\infty} \left( \sum_{j=1}^N a_j + \sum_{k=1}^N b_k \right) \text{provided that both of} \\
& \qquad \text{the limits on line $(1)$ above exist and are finite.}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy This proof seems circular to me. How do you justify rearranging the series without showing it absolutely converges?

Comment: @Kaind : I was perfectly explicit about absolute convergence in comments above, and the only series that gets rearranged in my last comment above has only finitely many terms.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to argue. As long as everyone's on the same page, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another crack at it: Just observe from the AM-GM inequality: $\sqrt{xy} \le \dfrac{x+y}{2}$ with $x = a_j, y = a_{j+1}$. The use of max and min of two numbers is correct but not necessary for this kind of question.